# Energy of mercury(II) oxide decomposition

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

*Study check 9.11* from [1, p. 298]:

> Mercury(II) oxide decomposes to mercury and oxygen.
>
> $$\ce{2 HgO -> 2Hg + O2}\quad ΔH = \pu{+182 kJ}$$
>
> […]
>
> **b**. How many kilojoules are needed when $\pu{25.0 g}$ of mercury(II) oxide reacts?

Correct answer is $\pu{20.5 kJ}.$ I get $\pu{10.5 kJ}.$ Here's how I did it:

1. Grams to moles: $200.59 + 16 = \pu{216.59 g}$ (using molar masses)

   $$\pu{25 g} × \frac{\pu{1 mol}}{\pu{216.59 g}} = \pu{0.12 mol}$$
2. Moles to kJ:

   $$\pu{0.12 mol} × \frac{\pu{182 kJ}}{\pu{2 mol}} = \pu{10.5 kJ}$$

What did I do wrong?

#### References

1. Timberlake, K. C. *Basic Chemistry*, 5th ed.; Pearson: Boston, **2016**. ISBN 978-0-13-413804-6.

Comment: Your calculation is correct, although you forgot to use the correct units. Delta H given in the tables is always in kJ/mol, and not in kJ. I don't know why the correct answer should be 20.5 kJ. Is it not a typing error ? 2 instead of 1 ?

Comment: This question is taken from a chemistry book (by Timberlake) and they've written the answer is 20.5 kJ

Comment: I agree with @Maurice that it's likely a typo and should be 10.5 kJ; you followed the procedure described on a previous page pretty closely. I flipped through the rest and the way textbook handles units, presents calculations and its overall structure left a sour taste in my mouth.

Comment: Alright thank you guys, i'd consider this question solved then